# Background Size - Cover

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to stretch an Image Full Screen (Cover): http://www.bootply.com/114850

I have a simple Menu and a call to action button but the image covers only the menu and stops there.

The Section Style is below.

```
.section-1 {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/fGrTemz.jpg);
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

section-1 is stretching to the height of its parent (html/body) which doesn't have a height set on so it doesn't know what height to be.

Comment: Tried that, but it still stays only on the navbar. You can Test it on the Bootply i supplied.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried it again and it works for me? I tried it on the Bootply... I'll see if I can send you a screenshot.

Comment: Or way more sensibly... just fork the Bootply. *facepalm*. Thanks Andrew :)

Comment: True, i made a mistake on the coma (,).. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your min-height from percentage to pixels.

```
.section-1{
    min-height:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Percentage height is dependent on the height of the parent**, so you need to "pass" the height in percentage to the targeted element.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Demo:** http://www.bootply.com/114867

Answer (score 0):

Yo specified `position:absolute` in your `.content-holder` so that it was removed from the content flow. As a result, its container `<section>` shrink its height to fit the `<nav>` element only.

Try remove `position:absolute` from `.content-holder`. And if you add `position:absolute` to `.section-1`, the background will be fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to you css:

```
position: Absolute
```

so your css would be

```
.section-1 {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/fGrTemz.jpg);
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add width:auto; to the section class. then just play around with the section-1 class  min-height in "px" to target the screen size that best suits you. essentially what you could do is use media queries to target different screen sizes that way you will always get the perfect size. but thats alot of work so use the

```
html, body{height: 100%;}
```